# Another Speed Boost Possible?

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Thanks to the respondents on this question ([This loop is very slow, I think because I create a lot of intermediate strings. How can I speed it up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396949/this-loop-is-very-slow-i-think-because-i-create-a-lot-of-intermediate-strings-h)) I was able to speed up my code many orders of magnitude.

I think I can probably do a bit better though. Is it possible to avoid the creation of a bunch of NSString's here, and instead split the big NSString (routeGeom) into a bunch of char buffers and iterate through those?

I have never done any C programming, so if you know how to get this done, it would be much appreciated!

```
NSTimeInterval start = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

NSString *routeGeom = [pieces objectAtIndex:1];
NSArray *splitPoints = [routeGeom componentsSeparatedByString:@"],["];

routePoints = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * ([splitPoints count] + 1));

int i=0;
for (NSString* coordStr in splitPoints) {

  char *buf = [coordStr UTF8String];
  sscanf(buf, "%f,%f,", &routePoints[i].latitude, &routePoints[i].longitude);

  i++;

}
```

Comment: Have you profiled and determined that splitting the string is taking up very much time?

Comment: Now that [neutrinos might be going even faster than c](http://science.slashdot.org/story/11/09/22/1841217/cern-experiment-indicates-faster-than-light-neutrinos), you might want to try an implementation using those.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *buf = [routeGeom UTF8String];
int bestGuess = 1 << (whatever);
routePoints = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * bestGuess);
for (int i = 0; buf != NULL; buf = strchr(buf+1,'['), ++i) {
  if (i >= bestGuess) {
      bestGuess <<= 1;
      routePoints = realloc(routePoints, sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * bestGuess);
  }
  sscanf(buf+1, "%f,%f,", &(routePoints + i)->latitude, &(routePoints + i)->longitude);
}
```

Pick a good starting value for `(whatever)` so that 2<sup>whatever</sup> is representative of an average number of points in a route.  If you can't, you could try guessing the number based on the length of the string.  Otherwise, if you want to be exact, you could parse the string twice, first counting, then create `routePoints`, then parse the data, in which case you wouldn't need the realloc section.

**Edit:**

Another option.  This assumes that CLLocationCoordinate2D is simply a struct of 2 floats, in the same order as the data in the string.

```
char *buf = [routeGeom UTF8String];
int bestGuess = 1 << (whatever);
float *tmpFloats = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * bestGuess);
float *index = tmpFloats;
for (int i = 0; buf != NULL; buf = strchr(buf+1,'['), ++i, index += 2) {
  if (i >= bestGuess) {
    bestGuess <<= 1;
    tmpFloats = (float *)realloc(tmpFloats, sizeof(float) * bestGuess);
  }
  sscanf(buf+1, "%f,%f,", index, index + 1);
}
CLLocationCoordinate2D *routePoints = (CLLocationCoordinate2D *)tmpFloats;
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this loop never ends for me.

Comment: I got this code working, but it's much slower than the original code.

Comment: If you have picked a bad choice for bestGuess, the code can become very slow, if it has to realloc the memory; If you can't come up with a good base values(overestimate rather than underestimate if estimation is necessary) it may be a good idea to count the number of sets first, then malloc, then parse the data.

Another idea would be to use memchr instead of strchr.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the realloc, theres a better way to do it. Also you shouldnt iterate over a loop using arrayname[index]. Instead use a pointer, ie

```
int array[5000];
int* intPointer = &array;
for(int i=0;i<5000;i++,intPointer++)
    *intPointer = something
```

Doing `&routePoints[i]` forces the CPU to do a '&routePoints + i*sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D)" multiple times per loop.

I would strongly recommend you get a book on C and learn it. You will benefit in the long run.

I know this answer does not immediately help you, but taking a really long string and breaking it up into smaller strings using C is actually a very common and simple thing to do (in a very fast and efficient way).

Answer (score 0):

You should really be using [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html) for this task -- bitbanging for miniscule performance increases really isn't worth the time.

Comment: Did you search for "scanner"?