# Why is this C-style code 10X slower than this obj-C style code?

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, cocoa-touch

//obj C version, with some - less than one second on 18,000 iterations

```
for (NSString* coordStr in splitPoints) {

  char *buf = [coordStr UTF8String];
  sscanf(buf, "%f,%f,", &routePoints[i].latitude, &routePoints[i].longitude);

  i++;

}
```

//C version - over 13 seconds on 18,000 iterations

```
for (i = 0; buf != NULL; buf = strchr(buf,'['), ++i) {

  buf += sizeof(char);
  sscanf(buf, "%f,%f,", &routePoints[i].latitude, &routePoints[i].longitude);

}
```

As a corollary question, is there any way to make this loop faster?

Also see this question: [Another Speed Boost Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397040/another-speed-boost-possible)

Comment: Why don't you dump the disassembly and look at the raw difference? Or use the profiler?

Comment: You know `sizeof(char) == 1` for all platforms, right?

Comment: What is ``splitPoints`` in the obj C version? I mean, the C version is splitting buf as it goes along ... and, apparently, the obj C version has done that by the time that snippet is reached.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Measure, measure, measure.

Measure the code with the Sampler instrument in Instruments.

With that said, there is an obvious inefficiency in the C code compared to the Objective-C code.

Namely, fast enumeration -- the `for(x in y)` syntax -- is really fast and, more importantly, implies that `splitPoints` is an array or set that contains a bunch of data that has already been parsed into individual objects.

The `strchr()` call in the second loop implies that you are parsing stuff on the fly.  In and of itself, `strchr()` is a looping operation and will consume time, more-so as the # of characters between occurrences of the target character increase.

That is all conjecture, though.  As with all optimizations, speculation is useless and gathering concrete data using the [rather awesome] set of tools provided is the only way to know for sure.

Once you have measured, then you can make it faster.

Comment: For what it's worth, I can't imagine `strchr()` being terribly inefficient. It's a simple function and should be fairly well optimized. That said, it can still be bad.

Comment: `strchr()` is fast.  The difference is that the array implies that parsing is already done and the loop w/`strchr` adds the cost of doing the parse in the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Having nothing to do with performance, your C code has an error in it. `buf += sizeof(char)` should simply be `buf++`.  Pointer arithmetic always moves in units the size of the type.  It worked fine in this case because sizeof(char) was 1.

Comment: Which has nothing to do with the question at hand.  To the compiler, sizeof(1), sizeof(char), and 1 are absolutely identical.  Thus, though a bug, it cannot be the source of the performance discrepancy.

Comment: Oh, come on.  That was a perfectly factual comment, and a useful style note;  needless use of sizeof is always a great clue that the code you are reading has pointer bugs in it.  And your correction is factually incorrect to boot.  sizeof(1) == sizeof(int) == 4 on most platforms

Comment: Factual, yes, but it has no relevance to the question at hand.  (Yes, I made a factual error in sizeof(1), too).

Answer (score 1):

Obj C code looks like it has precomputed some split points, while the C code seeks them in each iteration. Simple answer? If N is the length of `buf` and M the number of your split points, it looks like your two snippets have complexities of O(M) versus O(N*M); which one's slower?

edit: Really amazed me though, that some would think C code is axiomatically faster than any other solution.

Comment: The C code is only looking for the next '[' in each iteration of the loop, not looking through the entire length of buf for every splitpoint, right?

Comment: No, but worst case scenario is that it'll have to traverse the entire string. So it's directly dependent on the length of the string, not constant.

Comment: Gah, I meant "yes, but". Need coffee.

Answer (score 0):

Vectorization can be used to speed up C code.

Example:

[Even faster UTF-8 character counting](http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2008-06-05-faster-utf8-strlen.html)

(But maybe just try to avoid the function call strchr() in the loop condition.)